# How do I increase the capacity of my university?

Tags: simcity-2013

I am stuck with an absolute maximum of 1800 students that I can force in my university, but I need 2000 to get the desired upgrade. The problem is that the capacity of the university is only 1300 students.

I already bulldozed all my community colleges, which pushed the number up to the already mentioned 1800, but it seems the university just cannot fit any more students than 1800 with the 1300 student capacity. I tried closing the school and getting rid of the school bus stops, but that didn't do anything except dropping my education level from 5 full hats to 4 full hats and leaving over 1000 kids/students without enrollment.

That's why I believe I have to somehow upgrade the capacity of my university, but I don't see how this is possible. I have 3 dormitories and one school of business plopped down and cannot build more until I have reached the 2000 students.

How is this system supposed to work? I definitely have enough kids/students in the city. Do I have to build a second university?

Comment: I managed to get it. It was close, 2040 students, but i got it. Thanks to all who replied, you were very helpful. The problem was indeed the mass transit system. I thought it was working perfectly, but when i checked, it turned out i did not place a freaking bus stop in front of my university. Rookie mistake! So i did that and it worked out, even though the buses drove around in the residential part of my city most of the day and only once reached my university bus stop, so i definitely experienced teeone's hint of students getting lost in mass transit, will have to look into that as well. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 4 classes daily.  Each class can teach the listed capacity.  This means your university already has room for 1300 * 4 = 5200 students.

Stop looking to increase capacity and start looking at traffic and flow.  Increase the number of students that can reach (and leave) the university.  If students are leaving the building by car at 9 PM, then you need more mass transit.

Comment: Alright, i will look into expanding my mass transit.

Comment: Using a circular city design (w/ the university in the middle) I've gotten one of my universities up to level 4. Now even though I've maxed out one or two of the classes at 2300/2300 I can never get the daily total higher than 3500/4500. So per my observations the students in the dorms will hold off for ~30 minutes after class starts and then swarm/fill the university, they may attend further classes but you don't seem to get credit for them. So in a long and about manner: it's about transportation.

Comment: This answer is definitely the problem you are experiencing. If you ONLY have a university in your city, traffic is absolutely critical to it being filled to maximum. You most likely have students not being able to reach it in time for class.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the maximum capacity of your university by adding additional schools (ie: school of law, school of business, school of science etc).

[image]

Each building will provide an increase to your university's maximum teaching capacity;

[image]

Universities can teach more students than its maximum number of students in class, so it's perfectly possible to teach an entire city full of students with just a university provided your students can all get to the university building using your mass transit system and road network.

Comment: Yeah, but to _build_ another additional school i need to reach those 2000 students first. As i said, i already tried removing all other education buildings, but it wont get over 1800 students. I have a very functioning bus system that covers the whole city, too.

Comment: That means your road system/mass transit isn't good enough to allow all of your students to get to university. Improve your road network (to reduce traffic jams) and improve your mass transit system (*not* school bus stops, universities use your city's mass transit system). If your students are getting stuck in traffic then they will never arrive at university, likewise if they're not within range of a mass transit stop and don't have a car they won't even bother trying to get to university.

Comment: I would like to add to kalina's comment that it's possible students getting 'lost' in your mass transit system and not reaching the school in time. Its very possible they are getting in stuck street cars, or your buses never reaching the university, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The EASIEST way to get more students is to just build more universities.  I ended with the same problem, but built 2 more universities and was able to unlock all the schools and do research on three different items at a time too boot.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem and first thing I found was **if** you have a community college in town, the Sims all will go there because it obviously cheaper than University. You'll need to demo those community colleges.

Secondly, view population statistic and see where most of students reside. Make sure you have buses stop on both side of the street. Of course if you have street cars, making sure your University school fronts are facing the road with street cars. I usually place 2 to 3 street car stop at any place with heavily commuters in this case in front of University.

Also, frequently check your transit system wait time including (buses & street cars) and check street car stops - see how many riders in a day. If you have high traffic in your town, don't increase buses; that's just going to make it worse. Instead, increase street cars and park & ride. Remember, street cars run on track so they are not stuck in traffic.

University dormitories increase students per day, since they don't need to travel far to classes. But remember it costs $$$ to stay in dorms (as in real life), so if most of your town are in the mid- or lower- wealth that could cause few students to stay in dorms. You may need to check the statistics, most students are working in local commercial places, not all of them are in dorms.