# Classrooms Full!

Tags: simcity-2013

I keep getting complains about people that couldn't go to school. How could I fix this? I tried a lot of things (like multiple universities and school bus stops everywhere). Not sure how to fix this. All streets are `High Density Streetcar Avenue`

---

I builded **two** universities in the opposite sides of the city, and still have the problem while both got "Classroooms full" warnings at 7:15 am

**Statistics:**

- 3.566 of 4.400 Students enrolled
- School bus stop in every place (all streets are green)
- I have kids not enrolled living in the building NEXT to the university (literally in the same quarter!!)
- First university:

  - 1600 of 4500 students in class today
  - 800/800 students in class today
  - 3 dormitories
- Second university:

  - 1600 of 4500 students in class today
  - 800/800 students in class today

**The layout of my city is more or less this:**

```
 _________________
|UrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrrrrrrrrrrrrrCCII|
|rrCrUrrrrrrrrrCCII|
```

Here some Screen shots!

[image: First U]
[image: Middle]
[image: Second U]

Comment: Related: [How do I increase the capacity of my university?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/how-do-i-increase-the-capacity-of-my-university)

Comment: if your classrooms are full then you need more capacity

Comment: @ratchetfreak Even if I build extra Universities, the problem still occurs. Looks more a traffic issue, but idk how to fix it. and if you look at the statistic part `1600 of 4500 students in class today
800/800 students in class today` I didn't understood why this numbers.

Comment: 800/800 is how many students/places in class rooms while 1600 of 4500 is how many get an education/how many students total. expand the uni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to misunderstand how Universities work.

- Universities have four classes a day: 6:00am, 9:00am, 12:00pm, and 3:00pm. At each of these times, any students in class will leave, and a call for more students will be put out.
- Over the course of these four classes, the University counts how many students it gets total for the day, which apparently in your case is 1600.
- At any one time, you can have a maximum of 800 students, hence the 800/800 number you see.
- After the "total students today" counter gets to a certain amount, you can upgrade the University so you can place down a new sub-school. **Each new sub-school increases how many students can be in class at once; this is how you increase the University's capacity.**
- There's no real point to having two separate Universities.
- Only Grade Schools and High Schools use school bus stops. College and University students do not take school buses, they walk, drive, or use public transit.
- If you don't have streetcars, don't bother upgrading to streetcar avenues, they're identical to high-density avenues aside from the streetcar tracks.

I can even see by your screenshots you've added a ton of dormitories, but no sub-schools. This is your problem: **You need to increase how many desks are open at once by using the University's upgrades to place sub-schools.** It's like a specialization HQ; you can upgrade it all you want, but you don't get any benefit until you put the extensions down.

Comment: +1 Just for emphases: `Only Grade Schools and High Schools use school bus stops. College and University students do not take school buses, they walk, drive, or use public transit.`